# Underscore template undefined inside a loop

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Using underscore templates. Looping through a backbone collection:

```
  <% _.each(venues, function (venue) { %>
  <tr>
    <td class="text-muted"><%= venue.get('city') %></td>
    <td class="text-muted"><%= venue.get('name') %></td>
    <td class="text-muted"><%= venue.get('live') == true ? "Yes" : "No" %></td>
    <td class="text-muted">$0.00</td>
    <td class="blank controls">
      <a href="#"><span class="icon icon-edit"></span><span class="text-hide">Edit</span></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <% }); %>
```

I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined
```

Comment: How are you embedding this in your HTML? Is it in a `<script>` tag? Or just stuck into the HTML?

Comment: @maegar it's a require.js text template.

Comment: `console.log(venues);`?

Comment: @thefourtheye works fine. it logs the venues and I can browse though the array through each model.

Comment: @muistooshort doing venues.each ... works, but _.each doesn't work. any idea why?

Comment: @0xSina You mean `venues.forEach`?

Comment: I have no idea why because I can't see it happening, hence the request for a demo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If venues is a Backbone.Collection, then it will have all of the underscore iteration methods mixed in.

Try:

```
<% venues.each(function (venue) { %>
  <tr>
    <td class="text-muted"><%= venue.get('city') %></td>
    <td class="text-muted"><%= venue.get('name') %></td>
    <td class="text-muted"><%= venue.get('live') == true ? "Yes" : "No" %></td>
    <td class="text-muted">$0.00</td>
    <td class="blank controls">
      <a href="#"><span class="icon icon-edit"></span><span class="text-hide">Edit</span></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
<% }); %>
```